# Visualize given temperatures on image/map/plane

Tags: visualisation

I am looking for a way to visualize some data of the form :

```
latitude longitude temperature
```

**as image(s)**. Have many of these 3-tuple lines uniformly distributed on a region.

Ultimately, I am looking for a dynamic way, but even a statically creation of an image would be fine.

I need the image in order to use it as an overlay for google maps (or something similar) and looking for an end result like the one [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjraO.jpg).

Comment: It seems you have already answered your own question! I've voted as off-topic, as this seems to be oriented towards a programmatic implementation.

Comment: @AndyW  What's the answer? I think you misunderstood some part of the question. I am looking for a way to get a visual result (image) of my data. And I do not have one.

Not necessarily looking for a programmatic implementation, even though that's my ultimate goal.

For now, even a simple program that accepts CSV data and visualizes them as an image output would be fine. I do not necessarily need to know how it works or how to automate it.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq). If the question were `How do I visualize such data?` that may be on topic, but how to get software to produce a map that looks like the one you cite is not. For software, I would suggest you peruse the work of [Tomislav Hengl](http://spatial-analyst.net/book/node). He has various examples in open source R, and has R libraries to export the map images to KML.

Comment: I believe that this is my question. Of course that only holds provided that the answer to 
`How do I visualize such data?` has to do with _how can I do it_ , ie **as image** is not an answer. 
I am sorry if my question is still out of stats.exchange topics. I thought that here was the right place to get an answer regarding the visualization of such data.
Thank you for the link, I will look up into it.